# Translation Question from Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone

Tags: translation, english-to-japanese

I have a question about the translation of this sentence from uncle Vernon in Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone:

Original Japanese:
"あいつらは身から出た錆、魔法使いなんて変な仲間と交わるからだ
…**思ったとおり、常々ろくな死に方はせんと思っておったわ**"

My translation:
"They got what they deserved, because they got involved with those 'wizard' weirdos...**Just as I thought, I thought there isn't always/usually a good/decent/satisfactory way of dying**."

Published English translation:
"Just what I expected, always knew they'd come to a sticky end."

I don't quite understand how the text in bold comes together here to form the intended meaning. I'm not looking for a smooth translation, rather just trying to grasp how the Japanese comes together here.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Going back to front: 常々**X**と思っておったわ (=常々Xと思っていたぞ) = "I've always thought that X!". せん is しない; Yはせん = = Yはしない = as for doing Y, they won't; it's an emphatic way of saying "they won't Y".  Y here is Z-na 死に方, a way of dying that's Z.  Z is ろくな = decent, respectable.  Putting it back together: I've always known that they'd have no such thing as a decent death.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks.  I mistook せん for a shortened version of ありません despite having learned that months ago!  Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Perhaps I'm nitpicking a bit, but Japanese is not the *original* and English is not the *translation*.  Unless JK Rowling secretly wrote the books first in Japanese and then had them translated into English, it's English that is the original and Japanese that is the translation.

Comment: @leoboiko Why did you post it as a comment?

Comment: @naruto you're right, that's an answer. Guess I was feeling insecure. I'll reformat it below.

Answer (score 3):

It parses as:

`╔ 常々
 ║    ╔ ろく-な
 ║  ╔╩═ 死に方-は
 ╠═╩═══ せん-と
 ╚ 思っておったわ`

Or, in standard Japanese:

`╔ 常々
 ║    ╔ ろく-な
 ║  ╔╩═ 死に方-は
 ╠═╩═══ しない-と
 ╚ 思っていたぞ`

Going outside in:

- "常々 **X** と思っておったわ" = "I've always thought that **X** ".

  - What was X they always thought? That "**Y** はせん" (= "**Y** はしない"). This means "as for Y, they won't do"; it's an emphatic way of saying "they won't Y".

    - What is Y that they won't do? To die in a decent way ろくな死に方。
- Putting it all back together: I've always known that they'd have no such thing as a decent death.